# How can I make PlotRangePadding working properly?

Tags: plotting

I am using the option `PlotRangePadding -> None` to make the curves exactly cut at the specified `PlotRange` and thus at the frame edges as follow:

```
plot= With[{XZ = 170, YZ = 230, m = 1.5}, 
  Plot[{-Sqrt[x^2 + 1], Sqrt[x^2 + 1], Sqrt[0.5 x], -Sqrt[0.5 x], 
    Sqrt[-0.5 x], -Sqrt[-0.5 x]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black}], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
     FontSize -> 16}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, ImagePadding -> 80, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

and then use  `Export["C:\\Users\\plot.pdf", plot]` to get the figure, but the curves extend to exist outside the frame, see green arrow on the below picture. However, the curves are nicely cut along the right side of the y-axis, see red arrow

[image]

Comment: You have conflicting goals. A theoretical line has no thickness, Since some thickness must be added to see or draw it, it is no longer constrained to be within its theoretical limits. You are compounding the problem by making the line `Thick`. You will need some small `PlotRangePadding`, e.g., `PlotRangePadding -> 0.03`. However, then you can have some small gaps at the plot edges.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, then why is the end of the curve along the right y-axis is perfectly aligned with the fram as indicated by the red arrow?

Comment: Perhaps happenstance?

Comment: @BobHanlon, I don't think so, I tried a lot of different plots and it is always the case!

Comment: Try `Export["C:\\Users\\plot.pdf", Image@plot];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick, CapForm["Butt"]}]` (`CapForm["Mitter"]` also works):

```
plot = With[{XZ = 170, YZ = 230, m = 1.5}, 
  Plot[{-Sqrt[x^2 + 1], Sqrt[x^2 + 1], Sqrt[0.5 x], -Sqrt[0.5 x], 
    Sqrt[-0.5 x], -Sqrt[-0.5 x]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick, CapForm["Butt"]}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black}], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
     FontSize -> 16}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, ImagePadding -> 80, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None]]

Export["plot.pdf", plot]
```

[image]

Comment: In 2D graphics, the default is `CapForm["Square"]`.